# replace app it was removed by mistek

Tags: applications

When I was going to factory setting for reset my mobile system after setting my previous aap is not present in my mobile.

So now what I do for recover it.

Comment: Of course not, that's what factory-reset is for. So no recovering, but re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

No replacing possible .
Factory reset will clean all apps and data. The only possibility is re installing.

Next time backup your apps and data.